# Как определить диапазон значений от и до за определенный шаг?

Tags: javascript, математика

Как я могу получить диапазон значений, например, от 200 до 1000 за 3 шага?

Comment: Что значит "за 3 шага"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кол-во чисел в диапазоне. Например, за 5 шагов от 200 до 1000 диапазон значений будет равен 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000

Comment: И что значит "получить диапазон"?

Comment: Шаг равен `(1000 - 200)/(N-1)`. Значения — соответственно `200 + i*шаг`. А вообще, какой-то, гм... странный вопрос. Мягко говоря.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. Можете оформлять как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разбивки диапазона (a,b) на N равноотстоящих значений надо просто сообразить, что *промежутков* между N значениями на самом деле N-1.

Итак, шаг между соседними значениями

```
h = (b-a)/(N-1)
```

а сами значения

```
xᵢ = a + i*h,  i = 0...N-1
```